# SQL Join returns empty records

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, join

How can I join and pool aggregate data from two tables A and B when table B has no record on it. I just want to show zero for all records in table A that has no matching records in table B with additional criteria. In this case I wanted to return the total number of items whose model value is 'cars'. This problem occurs when table B is empty.

Here is my code snippet:

```
SELECT 10 as No,'Total' as Label, 
                SUM(CASE WHEN (a.year = b.year) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Value,
                (a.Year) as Year
FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.year = b.year
WHERE (isDeleted = 0 OR isdeleted is null) and b.model='cars'
GROUP BY a.year
order by YearMonth asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
WHERE (isDeleted = 0 OR isdeleted is null) and b.model='cars'
```

if `b` is empty, then `b.model` will be `null` and your where clause willfilter those records out.  You should move that condition to your `JOIN` clause:

```
FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.year = b.year and b.model='cars'
WHERE (isDeleted = 0 OR isdeleted is null)
```

Note that your `SUM` can just be a `COUNT` instead since null values are not counted:

```
COUNT(b.year) AS Value,
```

Comment: Thanks. Value has something to show now but null is being displayed for (a.Year) as Year. Any solution?

Comment: Do you have any `null` values for year in `A`?  If so what do you want to do with them?

Comment: No. I've list of year values in A. A can not be null at all

Comment: @aby Then I do not see how you can get back null for (a.Year).  Are you sure you're just selecting `a.Year` - you aren't calling any functions or doing any operation on it?

Comment: My bad. Sorry for taking your time. I made some trivial errors. Now, it works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Move b.model='cars' from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause (otherwise a regular inner join is performed.)

```
SELECT 10 as No,
       'Total' as Label, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN (a.year = b.year) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Value,
       (a.Year) as Year
FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b ON a.year = b.year and b.model='cars'
WHERE (isDeleted = 0 OR isdeleted is null) 
GROUP BY a.year
order by YearMonth asc
```